# RCP product running in background in Windows 10

Tags: eclipse-plugin, windows-10, eclipse-rcp

We have an 64 bit RCP product which works perfectly in windows 7 and windows 8.1 but it is running in background in windows 10 as soon as it is opened.

How can I stop it from running in background?

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Do you mean the window will be in the background or it will be running headless? If the window will be in the background, try to replace the `exe` file of your RPC application with the `exe` file of Eclipse Oxygen.2.

Comment: There was an error in the perspective class, bcoz of which it was running in the background. Fixed the perspective issue and it works fine.